How to fix a pivot table error in my code?
I keep getting an 1004 error ( reference isn't valid ) for a specific line in my code.
Specific Line :
    ' Create the PivotTable
    Set pt = ptCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=ptSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
        TableName:="PivotTable773")

Full Code :
Sub CreatePivotTableFor773()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ptSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ptCache As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ptRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim wsName As String
 
    wsName = "PivotSheet"
 
    ' Set your worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your data sheet name
 
    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
    ' Create a new sheet for the PivotTable
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ptSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0
 
    If ptSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set ptSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ptSheet.Name = wsName
    Else
        ptSheet.Cells.Clear
    End If
 
    ' Loop through column A to find the value "773" and create the data range
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If cell.Value = 773 Then
            If dataRange Is Nothing Then
                Set dataRange = cell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set dataRange = Union(dataRange, cell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
 
    If dataRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found for 773", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
    ' Set the range for the PivotTable
    Set ptRange = dataRange
 
    ' Create a PivotCache
    Set ptCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=ptRange)
 
    ' Create the PivotTable
    Set pt = ptCache.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=ptSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
        TableName:="PivotTable773")
 
    ' Configure the PivotTable
    With pt
        .PivotFields("Supply").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Number").Orientation = xlColumnField
        .PivotFields("Year").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Month").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Quantity").Function = xlSum
    End With
 
    MsgBox "Pivot Table created successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub

I have tried multiple iterations / help, but the code does not create a new pivtot table. Can anyone help me to rewrite or point out the error. Thank You !

Do you still get the error if you omit TableName:="PivotTable773"?

I think there might be 2 issues with your dataRange/ptRange (and maybe a 3rd).
First is that it looks like you are just picking rows from the data and may not necessarily have a proper header row included.
Second is that I'm guessing .EntireRow is also including a bunch of blank columns (definitely a problem if your first data row is assumed to be the header row).
Maybe a third is that if they aren't contiguous rows, I'm not sure that you can make a pivot table from that.
